# create a heatmap based on object overlap

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

How can I create a heatmap in the shading tab? I have a number of circle objects with different sizes and all have the z coordinate set to 0. How do I change the heatmap to be based on how many circles are overlaid on each other? I attached an image of what I currently have and of a heatmap I made using ImageJ (what I want the blender heatmap to look like).

[image]
[image]
[image]